# How to apply a function to each sublist in scheme or racket?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

How to get the product of each sublist?
Tried:

```
(apply map * '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

but it returns: '(3 8)
while it should return '(2 12)

Comment: Try `(map (curry apply *) '((1 2) (3 4)))` instead.

Comment: thx :)
but how does it work? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pattern matching

```
(map (λ (xs) (match xs [(list a b) (* a b)]))
     '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

... Or you can use `map` with a lambda that applies `*` to the sublists

```
(map (λ (xs) (apply * xs))
     '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

... Or you can use `curry` to replace the lambda

```
(map (curry apply *) '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

Comment: excelent :)
could you recommend a resource on pattern matching?
and explain the curry line?

Answer (score 1):

A loop can be written with "named let":

```
(define (f l)
  (let loop ((l l)
             (ol '()))
    (cond
      [(empty? l) (reverse ol)]
      [else (loop (rest l)
                  (cons (apply * (first l)) ol))])))

(f '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

Output:

```
'(2 12)
```